# jQuery slider's compatibility with browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

I've just installed slider (slide show) script to my website's header. I have problem now compatibility with browsers. In 1st second after refresh page in chrome looks like (As you see half background white and header still not loaded.):
[image: chrome]

1st second after refresh with opera browser (As you see all background is white, logo and header not loaded):

[image: opera]

How It should be (With FireFox no problems):
[image: should be]

(P.S. with Internet Explorer at all my design is terrible (no rounded corners, no transparent menu, buttons without colors, and slide show not loading at all...)

Here is my `<head>` where is used js.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Efektyvi reklama socialiniame tinkle Facebook</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iecss.css" />
<![endif]-->
        <!-- Attach necessary JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.orbit-1.2.3.min.js"></script>    

            <!--[if IE]>
                 <style type="text/css">
                     .timer { display: none !important; }
                     div.caption { background:transparent; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000,endColorstr=#99000000);zoom: 1; }
                </style>
            <![endif]-->

        <!-- Run the plugin -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {
                $('#featured').orbit();
            });
        </script>
</head>
```

I found problem file why with opera and chrome not loading, this line `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>` I added It with slider. If I remove It, working successfully. I can't enter code here, because It so long. I uploaded It here: http://speedy.sh/FV3Qe/jquery-1.5.1.min.js I nothing understand in this code...

Maybe could you suggest other slider?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Wy are you using such an ancient version of Jquery?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I found this slider and used It, thats why, could you suggest other one?

Answer (score 0):

It is advised to move all your external JavaScript includes to the footer. The reason for this advice is sound and pretty simple. Nothing below the non asynchronous or deferred script tags gets rendered until the script is downloaded, parsed and executed.

There are quite a few technical reasons why scripts block. You need a "stable" DOM while executing a script. Browsers need to make sure document.write works.

You can find more information about the jQuery bottlenecks here:
http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/02/17/stop-paying-your-jquery-tax

Comment: Thank you for answer. How can I use document.write?

Comment: document.write is a method that provides a way of incorporating strings into the HTML content of the page. You don't have to worry about that, just move your external JavaScript include tags to the footer area.